# PHP tidy removes <span>

Tags: php, html, tidy

My code looks like that

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
....
Some HTML
...
<div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;"> 
                    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span> 
                    <strong>Alert:</strong> Sample ui-state-error style.</p>
                </div>
  ....
Some HTML
...  
<?php
$markup = ob_get_clean();

// Specify configuration
$config = array(
    'indent' => true,
    'output-xhtml' => true,
    'wrap' => 200);

// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($markup, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

// Output
echo $tidy;
?>
```

Getting result without `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>`. What am I missing? Maybe TIDY class removing empty tags? If yes, How can I prevent it?

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: @Truth yeah. found nothing. That's why posted question here

Comment: Have you tried the `drop-empty-paras` option, it's defaulted to true and might be causing the problem

Comment: @BenGriffiths but it's not <p> tag

Comment: No but it's possible it's doing it to the span too, there's no other empty tag option so it's worth a quick test to rule it out as a possible answer

Comment: @BenGriffiths just tested, got error : Unknown Tidy Configuration Option

Comment: Have you tried adding `&nbsp;` or some text inside the `span` to be sure that is removed because it's empty?

Comment: Odd, it's in the ref: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html

Comment: @Oriol `&nbsp;` worked. Thx mate. Post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted a comment: "Have you tried adding `&nbsp;` or some text inside the span to be sure that is removed because it's empty?". And it seems that `&nbsp;` worked.

So if somebody has the same problem and comes here, the solution is:

**Add `&nbsp;` inside the empty element.**

Comment: Yes, but it's a little stupid. Nowadays people use font awesome wit it's <i class='fa fa-arrow-down'></i> and stupid tidy totally ignores 'drop-empty-paras'    => false.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32912067/752603 works as a better answer now.